# Android: Possible to edit a DatePicker's layout?

Tags: android, kotlin

In my app, I would like to have a fragment that presents the user with a calendar from which they can click on a date which takes them to another fragment where they can create a record of how many hours were worked on a given project on that day. The calendar fragment should be able to display any existing records for hours worked, on the days they were worked. The final product would resemble something like this:

[image]

From this description, a DatePicker calendar sounded like the perfect solution. However, the biggest problem would be displaying the hours already on record for any given day on the calendar itself. From my research so far, I can't tell if it's possible to change the layout of the DatePicker or insert any form of text on a per-date basis.

My question is this: Is it possible to change the layout/details of a DatePicker? And if not, are there any alternative structures that may work better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to change the layout/details of a DatePicker?

Not in the way that you are thinking, sorry. You have no control over the structure of the UI elements, such as the text in the calendar day cells.

> And if not, are there any alternative structures that may work better?

There are a few dozen [open source date and time picker libraries](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/27?sort=created) that you could either use directly or fork to create your desired UI.

Or, get the source code to `DatePicker`, along with its layouts and other resources, fork them into your project, and then adjust that to look the way that you want.

Otherwise, use `ConstraintLayout` (or possibly `RecyclerView`, depending on your scrolling plans) to create your own calendar-style UI.